# Does my proof make sense? Functional analysis related

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence in $X$ with limit point $x$. I want to show that $(||x_n||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converging to $||x||$.

**My proof:** We have that for $\varepsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that $||x_n - x||<\varepsilon$. Define $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon + 2||x||>0$. Using the reverse triangle inequality we have that $||x_n||<\varepsilon + ||x||$.

Now, $|||x_n|| - ||x|||<||x_n|| + ||x||<2||x|| + \varepsilon = \varepsilon'$. Thus by defintion of convergence we have that $||x_n||\rightarrow\ ||x||$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I'm sure there's more elegant proofs, I just want to know if this is correct. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct, since you wrote $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon + 2||x||$ and later you wrote $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon + 2||x_n||$

A very simple proof follows from $|||x_n|| - ||x||| \le ||x_n-x||$

Comment: Edit made. Correct now? Thank you

Comment: No. $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon + 2||x|| >2||x||$ . If $x \ne 0$ then you never get  $\varepsilon' $ arbitraryly small.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of convergence does not work because **$\epsilon'=\epsilon+2\|x\|$ cannot be made arbitrary small.** Notice that $\epsilon'\ge 2\|x\|$. Take the estimation as @Fred suggests.